# How to make Synchronous ASIO thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, asio

Could someone please explain to me how to become thread safe in my situation. Ive read multiple contradictory sources and the documentation is really indistinct.

Below is some pseudo code trying to summarise my situation.

### My Situation in pseudo code.

```
LowLevelHardwareLinkClass
{
    Contructor()
    {
        // Spawn local thread to create UDP socket and async read it -> CreateUDPSocket().
    }

    private CreateUDPSocket()
    {
        // Creates the socket and connects to server.
        // Call UDPSocketAsyncReading() to register read
        // Run io_context.run() for UDP socket.
    }
    
    private UDPSocketAsyncReading()
    {
        // Do socket.async_receive_from and logic to handle read data.
        // Recursive call to this same function -> UDPSocketAsyncReading().
    }
    
    public ConnectToTCPServer()
    {
        // Create a local TCP socket and connection to the server.
        // Spawn a local thread to keep reading from this socket -> KeepReadingTCPSocketSync()
    }
    
    private KeepReadingTCPSocketSync()
    {
        // inside a while loop, keep calling tcpSocket.receive() and write to local buffer. 
        // (This is a sync call that will block until bytes are read.)
    }
    
    public ShutDownTCPSocket()
    {
        // Outside thread comes in to call 
        // 1. TCP_io_context.stop()
        // 2. tcpSocket.close().
    }
    
    public ShutDownUDPSocket()
    {
        // Outside thread comes in to call 
        // 1. UDP_io_context.stop()
        // 2. udpSocket.close().
    }
    
    public ReadTCPData()
    {
        // Outside thread comes in to read the local buffer that `KeepReadingTCPSocketSync()`
        // writes to. Local buffer is protected with a mutex.
    }
    
    public WriteTCPData()
    {
        // Outside thread comes in with data to write on the tcp socket using tcpSocket.write_some().
        // This is a blocking sync call.
    }
}
```

### My Situation summarized in text.

I have a class with:

- 1 UDP io_context and UDP socket
- 1 TCP io_context and TCP socket
- 1 local Thread spawned to read the UDP socket asynchronously (will register the read handler and call io_context.run(), inside the handler will recursive call the function to reigster the handler therefore it will keep reading until the io_context is told to stop or the socket is closed.)
- 1 local Thread spawned to synchronously read the TCP socket using [Receive](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.24.0/doc/asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/receive/overload1.html) and write to a local buffer (the buffer has a mutex)
- 1 external thread that will come to read the buffer that the above thread writes to.
- 1 external thread that will come to write on the TCP socket using [write_some](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.24.0/doc/asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/write_some/overload1.html)
- 1 external thread to come in and close the TCP and UDP sockets and IO-contexts.

**I currently have no mutexes protecting access to the TCP or UDP sockets or io_contexts.**

### Question

Am I or am I not supposed to have mutex protection for accessing the sockets and/or calling any/explicit functions on the sockets?

This [documentation](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.24.0/doc/asio/overview/core/threads.html) says `it is safe to make concurrent use of distinct objects, but unsafe to make concurrent use of a single object` but this [documentation](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/doc/asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) says `Synchronous send, receive, and connect operations are thread safe with respect to each other, if the underlying operating system calls are also thread safe. This means that it is permitted to perform concurrent calls to these synchronous operations on a single socket object. Other synchronous operations, such as open or close, are not thread safe.`

So reading this makes me think that i dont need a lock for any reading or writing in my situation but i need one for opening and closing? And that there are maybe other function calls that need thread protection but they are not specified?

If someone could please clarify how and when exactly your supposed to use mutexes when dealing with synchronous socket calls from multiple threads, i think that would be a great help to anyone trying to use and understand ASIO.

Comment: The questions you asked are exactly answered in the documentation that you cited. Socket objects (all member variables and functions) are not thread safe, with the exception of the listed synchronous operations. How is that unclear?

Comment: By the way calling `io_context.run()` inside a handler sounds like a very bad idea. You should probably try to understand asio's execution model better. I found the boost::beast documentation (especially [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io.html) and [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/asio_refresher.html)) to be a good introduction to asio.

Comment: Hi Jakob, thanks for the clarification. To answer your question, it is not clear to me because its plastered all over the documentation that concurrent use of objects is not safe. This is the only place i found that mentions that some synch calls are safe. And it doesnt sound very confident too, i would also like to know what other sync calls are not safe but it doesnt list them making me untrustful of the documentation and questioning its accuracy. So i understand correctly that i only need a lock for open and close on the socket object.

Comment: And in regards to `io_context.run()`, my mistake of not being more explicit. I meant to say the method will call to register the handler and then after that call the `io_context.run()`. The handler will not call this, it only calls its own registration after it has finished read. Also thank you for the links provided.